# How to split text file like this in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
N-Heptane   100.20
Hexane  86.17
Hydrochloric Acid   36.47
Hydrogen, H2    2.016
Hydrogen Chloride   36.461
Hydrogen Sulfide    34.076
Hydroxyl, OH    17.01
Krypton 83.80
Methane, CH4    16.044
Methyl Alcohol  32.04
Methyl Butane   72.15
Methyl Chloride 50.488
Natural Gas 19.00
Neon, Ne    20.179
Nitric Oxide, NO    30.006
Nitrogen, N2    28.0134
Nitrous Oxide, NO2  44.012
N-Octane    114.22
Oxygen, O2  31.9988
Ozone   47.998
N-Pentane   72.15
Iso-Pentane 72.15
Propane, C3H8   44.097
Propylene   42.08
```

the text content like this, i'd like to split the string in Molecular Formula and Molecular weight

e.g

```
{"Hydrogen, H2":2.016, "Hydrogen Chloride":36.461, etc........}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply iterate over each row and use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit) to retrieve last white-space separated value as your dictionary value. Rest of line goes to it as a key.

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        d[key] = float(value)
```

Comment: Your "concise form" is slightly different: it creates`{str: str}`, not `{str: float}`.

Comment: Or, `di={k:float(v) for k, v in (line.rsplit(None, 1) for line in f)}`

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus obviously, thanks. dawg's comment is a correct one liner.